# I am getting Error in Asp.Net MVC "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The project was working correctly with no exception, then i started to get this error suddenly. I searched this error on forums and figured something about Razor so i updated Visual Studio but nothing changed. Details as below:

cshtml:

```
               <div class="small-box bg-success">
                    <div class="inner">

                        <h3> @ViewBag.countActivityFinish </h3>

                        <p>Tamamlanan Aktivite Sayısı</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="/Activity" class="small-box-footer">Aktiviteleri Gör <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                </div>
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["user"] == null) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");

        conn.Open();

        User withEmailToUser = conn.Query<User>("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Email = @Email", new User() { Email = Session["user"].ToString() }).FirstOrDefault();

        List<UserWrongLoginLog> userWrongLoginLogs = conn.Query<UserWrongLoginLog>("SELECT * FROM [UserWrongLoginLog] WHERE UserId = @UserId", new UserWrongLoginLog() { UserId = (Guid)withEmailToUser.Id }).ToList();    
        foreach (var item in userWrongLoginLogs)
        {
            conn.Execute("DELETE FROM [UserWrongLoginLog] WHERE Id=@Id", item);
        }

        int countCompany = conn.Query<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Company WHERE IsDelete = @IsDelete", new Company() { IsDelete = false }).FirstOrDefault();
        int countContact = conn.Query<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Contact WHERE IsDelete = @IsDelete", new Contact() { IsDelete = false }).FirstOrDefault();
        int countActivityWaiting = conn.Query<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Activity WHERE Status = @Status", new Activity() { Status = 0 }).FirstOrDefault();
        int countActivityFinish = conn.Query<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Activity WHERE Status != @Status", new Activity() { Status = 0 }).FirstOrDefault();

        conn.Close();

        withEmailToUser.UserWrongLoginLogs = userWrongLoginLogs;

        ViewBag.countCompany = countCompany;
        ViewBag.countContact = countContact;
        ViewBag.countActivityWaiting = countActivityWaiting;
        ViewBag.countActivityFinish = countActivityFinish;
        ViewBag.user = withEmailToUser;
        return View();
    }
```

my error:
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: This error obviously tells you that you bind a value to an object that is null. As I see, I guess it happens in line `withEmailToUser.UserWrongLoginLogs = userWrongLoginLogs` and it's because your `withEmailToUser` object is null

Comment: no there are no nulls in the controller part.

Comment: Deleting @ViewBag.countActivityFinish gives an error in the viewbag above it. 
bottom viewbag on new page gives this error

Comment: Please try a default value for `ViewBag.countActivityFinish` in controller, I think it fix your exception; Example : `ViewBag.countActivityFinish= countActivityFinish??0`

Comment: When I follow the steps value by value, it sounds like I want. But for some reason the latest viewbag always throws an error

Comment: Related to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1eb3f1c8-db17-4f2d-a778-1f789054593b/cannot-perform-runtime-binding-on-a-null-reference?forum=aspmvc in one of your ViewBags binding value, you set null to it and exception occurred. So try to bind the default value for your latest ViewBag to prevent error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting and recreating my view page, pasting the same codes fixed my problem.